# Is it dangerous to use hamachi for sharing game servers

Tags: network

I'm sure most of you are aware of a game called Minecraft. Well a lot of people like to host servers, however many are unable to port forward or pay for hosting so they download and use a piece of software called Hamachi.

It seems to allow them to form a connection group that acts as if they are all on the same router when they are not. This is becoming a widely used and I was wondering if there is a risk to it.

Because its young children who are using this, they are most likely to be a risk of being tricked.. I'm curious to the damage that could be done and to who.. Would only the host be affected or will others in the group as well.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. Can you explain further?

Comment: So some random person setups a Minecraft server with hamachi and I connect to it, is it possible for him to attack me or possible for me to attack any easier then other methods like getting someone's IP via Skype. Is connecting to a public hamachi network safe?

Comment: It might help if you explained what hamachi is and what your concerns with it are.

Comment: Hamachi is pretty well known..

Comment: Hey there! the best thing to do for hosting an MC server is obviously running it on a dedicated machine, or renting it with a MC host, when going on about dedicated machines, it will use your public IP address, but you can manage the firewall to isolate the traffic, using a domain (i.e. mc.arcaniacraft.nl) hides your IP from the basic skiddies, which are actually the biggest threat for MC servers, the skiddies that only know how to push buttons, nothing more. i'd NEVER suggest hamachii, because you basicly give (partial) access to your network via that

Answer (score 5):

I'm going out on a limb here and going to say you are talking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_(software)

Since its a publicly available VPN, connecting to a Hamachi network is a lot like connecting you your own LAN; except for the fact that EVERYONE on the Hamachi network you are connected to is unknown and can pose a very real threat to anyone on the network. Since you are essentially providing a door into your own network without some of the more external safety precautions, I wouldn't be surprised if there were some unscrupulous people taking advantage of it.

Be careful!

Answer (score 0):

Its not the best to use where you might be connecting to others that are not trusted, it allows for there to be a virtual Lan, so they are considered part of your shared network if you have one. Which can create devastation if you have sensitive or private data or information you do not really want to share.

Hamachi was not designed to be used in the ways many have been using it for. But thats not to say it isn't a wonderful product for many different environments.

In short:

Use it with trusted people only. Do not let your Hamachi pipe be accessible to others without a key.

If you are going to use it to connect to the public where anyone can access you, you are asking for possible security issues.